# Cross Platform RSA Encryption C# to Java and Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, android, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have generated an RSA key size of 1024 in my Windows form application. The code for the test application is as follows:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static CspParameters cspParameters;
        const string keyName = "TestKey1";
        private static RSACryptoServiceProvider devrsa;
        private RSAParameters publicKey;
        private RSAParameters privateKey;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cspParameters = new CspParameters();

            cspParameters.KeyContainerName = keyName;
            devrsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParameters);
            devrsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;

            publicKey = devrsa.ExportParameters(false);
            privateKey = devrsa.ExportParameters(true);

            var mod = publicKey.Modulus;
            var exp = publicKey.Exponent;

            var pubKey = new PublicKey
            {
                modulus = Array.ConvertAll(mod, b => unchecked((sbyte)b)),
                exponent = Array.ConvertAll(exp, b => unchecked((sbyte)b)),
            };

            var sPubKey = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pubKey);

            var bytePubKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sPubKey);

            PrintByteArray(bytePubKey);
        }


        public void PrintByteArray(Byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("new byte[] { ");
            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                sb.Append(b + ", ");
            }
            sb.Append("}\n");
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

public class PublicKey
{
    [JsonProperty("modulus")]
    public SByte[] modulus { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("exponent")]
    public SByte[] exponent { get; set; }
    public PublicKey()
    {

    }
    public PublicKey(SByte[] modulus, SByte[] exponent)
    {
        this.modulus = modulus;
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }
}
```

I take a copy of the console printed out byte array and use it as input in my Test Android Application. The Test android application is supposed to take the public key as input and use the imported public key to encrypt a sample text string.

The Code for the Android Application is as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        retrieveElements()
    }


    fun retrieveElements() {
        val request = ByteHelper.pubKey
        var key = ByteHelper.retrieveKey(request)

        val cipher = createCipher(key)

        encrypt(cipher)

    }

    fun createCipher(publicKey: PublicKey): Cipher {
        val modulus = BigInteger(publicKey.modulus)
        val exponent = BigInteger(publicKey.exponent)

        var spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent)
        var fact = KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)

        var publicKey = fact.generatePublic(spec)

        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
        return cipher
    }

    fun encrypt(cipher: Cipher)
    {
        val testString = "This is a test string"

        val stringBytes = testString.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)

        val encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes)

    }
}

class ByteHelper
{
    companion object
    {
        val pubKey = byteArrayOf( 123, 34, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 117, 115, 34, 58, 91, 45, 55, 49, 44, 45, 51, 50, 44, 45, 55, 44, 45, 49,
            48, 55, 44, 45, 51, 54, 44, 45, 51, 54, 44, 51, 54, 44, 45, 56, 44, 45, 51, 48, 44, 45, 49, 50, 53, 44, 45, 52, 44, 49,
            48, 48, 44, 45, 54, 49, 44, 45, 56, 48, 44, 45, 55, 53, 44, 50, 44, 52, 44, 49, 50, 51, 44, 52, 50, 44, 53, 54, 44, 45,
            53, 49, 44, 54, 55, 44, 45, 55, 44, 57, 55, 44, 49, 48, 54, 44, 45, 49, 49, 55, 44, 45, 49, 49, 57, 44, 45, 49, 49, 54,
            44, 45, 49, 50, 50, 44, 45, 50, 53, 44, 45, 55, 51, 44, 45, 51, 51, 44, 55, 49, 44, 45, 54, 53, 44, 53, 48, 44, 51, 50,
            44, 45, 51, 49, 44, 45, 49, 48, 56, 44, 45, 55, 49, 44, 45, 49, 49, 51, 44, 53, 53, 44, 45, 49, 49, 48, 44, 53, 55, 44,
            45, 55, 50, 44, 50, 44, 51, 49, 44, 51, 52, 44, 45, 49, 49, 48, 44, 55, 48, 44, 45, 57, 54, 44, 45, 57, 48, 44, 52, 52,
            44, 49, 49, 48, 44, 45, 49, 48, 55, 44, 45, 50, 53, 44, 45, 49, 56, 44, 49, 53, 44, 45, 51, 50, 44, 45, 56, 52, 44, 45,
            53, 44, 51, 53, 44, 45, 49, 48, 44, 45, 54, 49, 44, 45, 53, 51, 44, 49, 50, 49, 44, 45, 50, 50, 44, 56, 53, 44, 45, 49,
            48, 48, 44, 45, 52, 55, 44, 57, 51, 44, 45, 49, 49, 54, 44, 57, 44, 49, 51, 44, 55, 50, 44, 49, 50, 49, 44, 45, 52, 48,
            44, 45, 54, 53, 44, 49, 48, 53, 44, 45, 52, 52, 44, 45, 51, 50, 44, 51, 53, 44, 49, 49, 54, 44, 49, 49, 57, 44, 50, 56,
            44, 45, 55, 53, 44, 52, 53, 44, 56, 52, 44, 45, 53, 55, 44, 49, 55, 44, 49, 49, 44, 45, 49, 53, 44, 45, 52, 51, 44, 45,
            56, 55, 44, 49, 51, 44, 45, 52, 57, 44, 51, 53, 44, 55, 49, 44, 45, 51, 48, 44, 45, 49, 48, 57, 44, 45, 50, 52, 44, 51,
            49, 44, 45, 51, 50, 44, 50, 54, 44, 45, 51, 56, 44, 49, 49, 56, 44, 45, 52, 49, 44, 45, 51, 52, 44, 49, 57, 44, 45, 49,
            50, 50, 44, 45, 54, 51, 44, 52, 48, 44, 50, 53, 44, 57, 54, 44, 45, 56, 55, 44, 52, 53, 44, 45, 53, 48, 44, 45, 53, 54,
            44, 45, 55, 48, 44, 45, 49, 48, 55, 44, 45, 56, 54, 44, 52, 55, 44, 49, 48, 53, 44, 45, 51, 44, 45, 53, 57, 44, 53, 52,
            44, 45, 49, 50, 49, 44, 56, 52, 44, 45, 51, 93, 44, 34, 101, 120, 112, 111, 110, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 91, 49, 44, 48,
            44, 49, 93, 125)

        fun retrieveKey(bytes: ByteArray) : PublicKey
        {
            var jsonString = String(bytes, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"))

            var publicKey = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, PublicKey::class.java)

            return publicKey
        }
    }
}

data class PublicKey(
    @SerializedName("modulus") var modulus: ByteArray,
    @SerializedName("exponent") var exponent: ByteArray
) {
    constructor() : this(ByteArray(0), ByteArray(0))
}
```

However, when I run the Android version of my application. I get the following error.

```
com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher.
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSACoreEngine.convertInput(RSACoreEngine.java:115)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindedEngine.processBlock(RSABlindedEngine.java:95)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding.encodeBlock(OAEPEncoding.java:199)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding.processBlock(OAEPEncoding.java:131)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:475)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
        at com.touchsides.myapplication.MainActivity.encrypt(MainActivity.kt:54)
```

Comment: @James K Polk As suggest this is the test application and all the required data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the createCipher function, the issue related to the conversion of the ByteArray to a BigInteger.

```
val modulus = BigInteger(1, publicKey.modulus)
val exponent = BigInteger(1, publicKey.exponent)

var spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent)
var fact = KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)

var publicKey = fact.generatePublic(spec)

var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
```

To allow for decryption on the other side the cipher instance needs to be changed from :

```
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding => RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding
```